# Send data from Arduino to server

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Is it possible if my arduino uno remains constantly connected to a computer through the usb port, for me to send data from its sensors to a server without some other piece of equipment?

If yes, are there any security concerns? Because the server won't know that the data is actually coming from an arduino device that is supposed to send him data or some other source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a very simple way to achieve this is to use [breakoutjs](http://breakoutjs.com/)
download and install, and upload the firmata sample to the arduino.
You'll have to right some JavaScript code that will take care of sending requests to the distant server.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to use any sort of client app in the host computer. But if there is no other way then I suppose this is a fairly good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would need some sort of tool that converts the serial commands into network commands. 
I would let the arduino send the raw sensor data via serial and let the tool convert it into a request for the server.
I'm assuming that it's a webserver you're talking about?  If you send a generic user-agent header, the server could not distinguish between a your tool and an regular browser.

Comment: I was kind of hoping to not have to use a client app in the computer that hosts the arduino. Is there some example hosted somewhere or a tutorial to get me started?